# Arraylist and ListView

Tags: arraylist, android-listview, listadapter

I have a ListView, I created a custom adapter because in every row there must be two ImageView.
My aim is to set on clicklistener one of them, and when I click it a new row must be created in a certain position in the list. 
I know that to achieve this I have to set onclickListener the imageView inside the adapter class, but how can I get access to the ArrayList of the ListView so that I can create new rows?

Comment: @timss Please don't do highlighting edits unless you are going to leave a result which is *consistent* and *correct*  You need to clean this up or revert it to the original.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm not sure what's too wrong with it, and would rather not have to suggest and edit just to revert it (>=2k rep for rollback). Seeing as it was accepted, I'd say feel free to either rollback it yourself or fix what may be problematic with the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the onClick() method in the onClickListener that you need:

```
public void onClick(View v){
  mArrayList.add(<some new data>, <the index of the row> + 1);
  mBaseAdapter.notifyDatasetCahged();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i haven't the variable mArrayList inside the adapter... It is in the activity...